# PyTorch Lightning training console output is weird

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

When training a PyTorch Lightning model in a Jupyter Notebook, the console log output is awkward:

```
Epoch 0: 100%|█████████▉| 2315/2318 [02:05<00:00, 18.41it/s, loss=1.69, v_num=26, acc=0.562]
Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Validating:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:09<00:00, 17.84it/s, loss=1.72, v_num=26, acc=0.500, val_loss=1.570, val_acc=0.564]
Epoch 1: 100%|█████████▉| 2315/2318 [02:04<00:00, 18.63it/s, loss=1.56, v_num=26, acc=0.594, val_loss=1.570, val_acc=0.564]
Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Validating:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 1: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:08<00:00, 18.07it/s, loss=1.59, v_num=26, acc=0.528, val_loss=1.490, val_acc=0.583]
Epoch 2: 100%|█████████▉| 2315/2318 [02:01<00:00, 19.02it/s, loss=1.53, v_num=26, acc=0.617, val_loss=1.490, val_acc=0.583]
Validating: 0it [00:00, ?it/s]
Validating:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 2: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:05<00:00, 18.42it/s, loss=1.57, v_num=26, acc=0.500, val_loss=1.460, val_acc=0.589]
```

Expectingly, the "correct" output from the same training should be:

```
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:09<00:00, 17.84it/s, loss=1.72, v_num=26, acc=0.500, val_loss=1.570, val_acc=0.564]
Epoch 1: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:08<00:00, 18.07it/s, loss=1.59, v_num=26, acc=0.528, val_loss=1.490, val_acc=0.583]
Epoch 2: 100%|██████████| 2318/2318 [02:05<00:00, 18.42it/s, loss=1.57, v_num=26, acc=0.500, val_loss=1.460, val_acc=0.589]
```

How comes epoch lines are uselessly repeated and split in this manner? Also I'm not sure what use the `Validating` lines are, since they don't seem to provide any information.

Training and validation steps from the model are as follow:

```py
    def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = train_batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = torch.nn.NLLLoss()(torch.log(y_hat), y.argmax(dim=1)) 
        acc = tm.functional.accuracy(y_hat.argmax(dim=1), y.argmax(dim=1))
        self.log("acc", acc, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, valid_batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = valid_batch
        y_hat = self.forward(x)
        loss = torch.nn.NLLLoss()(torch.log(y_hat), y.argmax(dim=1)) 
        acc = tm.functional.accuracy(y_hat.argmax(dim=1), y.argmax(dim=1))
        self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True)
        self.log("val_acc", acc, prog_bar=True)
```

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to this? Im facing similar issue as well

Comment: @HardianLawi yes, by writing my own console output routine eventually

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when terminal windows are resized. The [default PL progress bar](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.3/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.html) uses tqdm and you can have issues if tqdm doesn't redraw the screen correctly.

The [PL docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/progress_bar.html) mention another, "rich" progress bar you might try instead, and also discuss how to write your own.

Answer (score -1):

By default, `Trainer` is configured to run the validation loop after each epoch. You can change this setting using `check_val_every_n_epoch` flag in `Trainer`. See docs [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#check-val-every-n-epoch).

Comment: Running validation every epoch is fine, but the output just seems messed up.